# How to determine the type of OS the service fabric cluster is running on

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to find out what type of OS(Win or Linux) my Service Fabric cluster is running on once you are connected to it. I need to determine the OS type the SF cluster is running on, so I can modify the ServiceManifest.xml endpoints names of Application endpoints accordingly. On Windows your endpoint needs to have *'.exe'* but if you deploy your service to a Linux cluster it's without it

**Windows**

```
<EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>MyApp.exe</Program>
      </ExeHost>
</EntryPoint>
```

**Linux**

```
<EntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>MyApp</Program>
      </ExeHost>
</EntryPoint>
```

I want to have only one *ServiceManifest.xml* in project and modify it accordingly

I've looked at *sfctl* and PowerShell CLI utility, but I can't find any info about what OS the clusters are running on.

Any idea how to determine the OS type once you connect to the cluster

**Update:**
I've found that if your cluster is running in Azure cloud you can use

`az sf cluster list` and there you can find `vmImage="Windows"` property. But you can't use this on **localhost**

Answer (score 0):

On **localhost** you can use regular PowerShell Core to find out what OS the script is running on:

```
[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Platform
```

Comment: This won't work in my case when I'm running a Linux cluster in Docker on a Windows machine. I need to know the target localhost OS I'm about to deploy